In what event (video) did Elon Musk start saying "...if Earth were a little heavier..." and then backtrack?
This comment says it all, but I'll quote the key part of it again here:

I also remember seeing Elon Musk mention this supposed limit, something like 'If Earth were a little heavier... conventional rockets wouldn't work...' then catch himself and say something like 'wait - is that right?' a few years ago in (the YouTube video of) some event. Possibly a Q&A session or press conference...

I'm quite certain I saw this and that my recollection is roughly correct. But I can not find it. It is not recent for sure. My guess is the 3 to 7 years ago time frame.
Question: When and where was this? Can someone help pinpoint this moment - find a YouTube or other video link for it?
edit: Here is an approximate example: transcript at the National Press Club in 2011 at about 08:26 in the video. However this particular quote is about reusable rockets. and not just about getting to space, and there is no backtracking. That could be the beginnings of another question which I will not ask :)

This is a very difficult thing to do because we live on a planet where that is just barely possible. If gravity were a little lower it'd be easier, but if it was a little higher it would be impossible. 

Since we have some ballpark numerical information showing that while there isn't a hard limit based on the rocketry, there is an amazing exponentially increasing need for rocket size as the earth gets heavier. 
While the 1.5 Earth limit suggested in the Tryanny of the Rocket Equation is a little premature, there is still the inevitabe Tyranny of the Exponential Equation to be dealt with!

I'm going to do some more hunting on this to make sure I'm not mixing two comments together. It was a long time ago.

I am not sure this is on topic. Stuff Elon says isn't necessarily useful space exploration information. It doesn't seem to be historically significant enough to be about space exploration history.

@kimholder ya I agree -  I'll delete it. Thanks!

I've temporarily undeleted this question for historical purposes - it might shed some light on the recent question Why, if gravity were higher, would designing a fully reusable rocket be impossible? Unless a reasonable answer magically appears, I'll re-delete it in a week.
